# When clearing comments on a cell, any pasted images nearby get deleted

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This is how I am inserting the picture: format it, cut it, paste it into the right cell and then grab it by the .top and .left. I've done it this way so that the picture will move with the rows when sorting (if I just .addpicture it won't get sorted).

...But now that I have solved the sorting problem, the .ClearComments started deleting the pictures instead of the comments. (It will also delete the comments, but it first deletes the pictures!)

Any ideas on how to solve this?

```
Dim myPicture as Picture
Dim pictShape as Shape     
Dim oCell as Range

    Set myPicture = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("http://img.youtube.com/vi/" & VideoURL & "/default.jpg")
    With myPicture
        .ShapeRange.PictureFormat.CropTop = 7.96
        .ShapeRange.PictureFormat.CropBottom = 8.225
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Height = pixHeight
        .Top = pixTop
        .Left = pixLeft
    End With
    Set pictShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(myPicture.Name)
    pictShape.Cut
    oCell.PasteSpecial
    For Each Sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Sh.Top = pixTop And Sh.Left = pixLeft Then 'found it!
            Sh.Name = "Picture " & i
            Exit For 
        End If
    Next Sh
    Set pictShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Picture " & i)
    With pictShape
        .Top = pixTop
        .Left = pixTop
    End With
```

Comment: Why not show the code you are using to clear comments? Isn't that where the problem is? Your solution has nothing to do with clearing comments.

Comment: The code I used to clear the comments was oCell.ClearComments (it's the built in one). The problem was not in the .ClearComments, it had stopped working because of the .PasteSpecial of my shape (it would delete my shape instead of deleting the comment). So I changed the .PasteSpecial it to .Paste and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. Do not use .PasteSpecial on shapes when planing to use .ClearComments, instead use .Paste.

```
    Set ExcSel = Selection ' save previous selection
    oCell.Select           ' select cell to paste to
    ActiveSheet.Paste      ' paste
    ExcSel.Select          ' select the originaly selected cell
```

Comment: Thanks for returning to share your solution. You will to wait 48 hours (as best as I can recall) but you will be able to return and mark your response as the accepted answer to the problem.

Comment: Glad to help anyone who runs into the same issue. Stackoverflow warned me I would have to wait the 48 hours, so here I am!